# How do I set the Result Type for items in a particular list?

Tags: 2013, search-results, display-template

I want to specify a display template to be used for items in a particular list. So everything in this list will use my custom display template.

I created a Result Type, but I don't know which condition to use. I've tried setting the ListId condition equal to my list's ID, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the format "{guid}"? Also have you added the ListID managed property to the ManagedProperty element in your display template?

http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2013/09/11/how-to-display-values-from-custom-managed-properties-in-search-results-option-1.aspx

Comment: I've discovered that my subsite isn't using the custom Result Types I've setup in my root site collection. It works if I manually add the Result Type to my subsite. I'm now trying to figure out how my subsite can inherit Result Types from my root site collection.

Comment: Seems the old link is dead. The "original" can be found on [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20131103015317/http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2013/09/11/how-to-display-values-from-custom-managed-properties-in-search-results-option-1.aspx)

Also it seems the article was migrated to [docs.microsoft.com](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/how-to-display-values-from-custom-managed-properties-in-search-resultsoption-1)